# uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `('29S','1803')` when I try to insert data to database when button is clicked($clientid=29s,$id=1803):

```
    if(isSet($_POST['CPH_GridView1_region']))
{
$region=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_region'];
$country=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_country'];
$networkname=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_networkname'];
$mcc=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_mcc'];
$mnc=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_mnc'];
$comment=$_POST['CPH_GridView1_comment'];

mysql_query("insert into globalnetwork(region,country,networkname,mcc,mnc,comment) values ('$region','$country','$networkname','$mcc','$mnc','$comment')");

}

$id = mysql_insert_id();
$sql_selectclientid="SELECT * from client_list";
$queryRes1 = mysql_query($sql_selectclientid);
print $sql_selectclientid;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryRes1)){ 
$clientid = $row['clientid'];   
print $clientid;
$sql_networkinsertid="insert into $clientid(clientid,net_id)values ('$clientid','$id')";
$query = mysql_query($sql_networkinsertid);
print $sql_networkinsertid;

}
```

myjquery

```
$(function() {
    $(".globalinsert_button").click(function() {

    var CPH_GridView1_region = $("#CPH_GridView1_region").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_country=  $("#CPH_GridView1_country").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_networkname=  $("#CPH_GridView1_networkname").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_mcc=  $("#CPH_GridView1_mcc").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_mnc=  $("#CPH_GridView1_mnc").val();
    var CPH_GridView1_comment=  $("#CPH_GridView1_comment").val();



    var dataString = 'CPH_GridView1_region='+ CPH_GridView1_region +'&CPH_GridView1_country='+CPH_GridView1_country+'&CPH_GridView1_networkname='+CPH_GridView1_networkname+'&CPH_GridView1_mcc='+CPH_GridView1_mcc+'&CPH_GridView1_mnc='+CPH_GridView1_mnc+'&CPH_GridView1_comment='+CPH_GridView1_comment;


    if(CPH_GridView1_region=='')
    {
    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else
    {
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "globalnetwork/insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#display").after(html);

    window.location = "?action=globalnetwork";
    $("#flash").hide();
    }
    });
    } return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: Your query is injectable, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/601524/2059127

Comment: $clientid couldn't be the name of your table :
insert into $clientid(clientid,net_id)